# In ASP MVC Div vs Partial View for portlets in a portal/dashboard. Which one is better performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, html, partial-views

We developed a dashboard, with partial views, and later advised to move to div's for performance.

Question:

1. If an ASP MVC dashboard containing widgets/portlets is constructed with Partial Views (for portlets) as opposed to Div's (for portlets), **what would the performance impact be?**

> i.e. **is the entire page/are all widgets/partial** views loaded and the
>   entire page redrawn for every time a part/partial view is touched/interacted/updated

1. I like partial views, for the way they're organized and reuse, is it possible to keep performance and still **get use out of the partial view design for the widgets/portlets**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

divs and Partial views are not mutually exclusive. You can put the content of a Partial inside a div, and include divs within it. In fact, you probably *should* use some sort of container HTML element to contain this sort of thing.

That said, the answer is; it depends. Well, the technical answer is, "Adding a partial view will *always* decrease performance over not adding one", but probably a very tiny amount. Then the real question is:

*Do you need the functionality of a Partial?*

Probably, you do.

You could always go more bare-bones and use an HTTP handler directly for your AJAX-loaded content, but; how much is your developer time worth?

To really know whether to use partials or go for something 'lower level', you'd really have to test. That said, I *suspect* you might be practicing a good bit of premature optimization here. You can always refactor your Partial result views for AJAX consumption into HTTP handlers later, if need be.

---

And no; when you load a partial view via AJAX or the like, there is no full 'page' in the context at all; what is generated is what your code calls.

Comment: I understand two things from your Response. 1) Yes, go ahead with partial views, and give them an ajax handler ASHX each 2) No, there is no additional roundtrip or overhead if the widgets are from a partial view vs putting them inside a div. Am I correct. Can I ask how you would have designed/partioned your widgets (for e.g. charts, calendar, map etc). Isolated Functional Fragements in a Dashboard

Comment: @aroos Yup, I think you've got mostly, except partial views in MVC aren't the same as the handlers. Http handlers are more "bare"; you don't get the model binding and such (which is why they can be a little more efficient). Generally, you'll wrap a "widget" in a div or something, and fulfill it with the result of a partial. Does that make sense?